# R adding rows of data and summarize them by group

Tags: r, group-by

After looking at my notes from a recent R course and here in the Q and As, the most probable function I need to use to get what I need would seem to be colsum, and groupby but no idea how to do it, can you can help me out.

( first I tried to look into summarize and group by but did not get far )

**What I Have**

```
player year  team  rbi
a      2001  NYY   56
b      2001  NYY   22      
c      2001  BOS   55
d      2002  DET   77
```

**Results wanted**

```
year  team rbi
2001  NYY  78
2001  BOS  55
2002  DET  77
```

The players name is lost, why ?

I want to add up the RBI for each team for each year using the individual players RBI's

So for each year there should be lets say 32 teams and for each of these teams there should be an RBI number which is the sum of all the players that batted for each of the teams that particular year.

Thank you

Comment: there are a lot of functions to aggregate data, for example, `aggregate(rbi ~ year+team, data=dat, FUN=sum)`, where `dat` is your data.  The player's name is lost because you are aggregating by unique combinations of year and team

Comment: It would be better if you showed your data in an easy copy/paste code and also the code you used to aggregate it.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` approach would be to convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'year' and 'team', we get the `sum` of 'rbi'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(rbi=sum(rbi)), by= .(year, team)] 
#   year team rbi
#1: 2001  NYY  78
#2: 2001  BOS  55
#3: 2002  DET  77
```

NOTE: The 'player' name is lost because we are not using that variable in the summarizing step.

Answer (score 2):

As per @bunk 's comment you can use the `aggregate` function

```
aggregate(df$rbi, list(df$team, df$year), sum )

#  Group.1 Group.2  x
#1     BOS    2001 55
#2     NYY    2001 78
#3     DET    2002 77
```

As per @akrun's comment to keep the column names as it is, you can use

```
aggregate(rbi ~ team + year, data = df, sum)
```

Comment: You can use the formula method to have the column names unchanged.  or `aggregate(list(rbi=df$rbi), list(team=df$team, year=df$year), sum )`

Answer (score 1):

Assume `df` contains your player data, then you can get the result you want by

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(year, team) %>%
   summarise(rbi = sum(rbi))
```

The players' names are lost because the column `player` is not included in the `group_by` clause, and so is not used by `summarise` to aggregate the data in the `rbi` column.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help resolving my issue, something that could have been done easier in a popular spreadsheet program, but I decided to do it in R, I love this program and it{s libraries although with a learning curve

There were 4 proposals to resolve my question and 3 of them worked fine, when I evaluate the answer by the number of rows the final run has because I know what the answer should be from a related dataframe.

1) Arun"s proposal worked fine and its using a novel library(data.table)  I read a little more on this library and looks interesting

```
  library(data.table) 
  setDT(df)[, .(rbi=sum(rbi)), by= .(year, team)]
```

2) Also Alexs proposal worked fine too, it was

```
  library(dplyr)
  df %>%
  group_by(year, team) %>%
  summarise(rbi = sum(rbi))
```

3) Akruns solution was also good. This is the one I liked the most because the team column came already in alphabetical order, it came sorted by year and team, while the previous two solutions you need to specify you wanted sorted by year and then team

```
  aggregate(list(rbi=df$rbi), list(team=df$team, year=df$year), sum )
```

4 ) Solution by Ronak almost worked, out of the 2775 rows that the results had to have this solution only brought 2761  The code was:

```
aggregate(rbi ~ team + year, data = df, sum)
```

Thanks again to everybody

Javier

Comment: `setDT(df)[, .(rbi=sum(rbi)), by= .(year, team)]` in solution 1 will be ordered too if you change `by` to `keyby`